# evaluation vs. execution (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

recently, start to learn Scheme (has been a week with my attention), so everything is really confusing and mixed up in my head. now realized that the expression "evaluation" is the main focus in the scheme.. compare with other "procedural language" languages, Scheme is a different world(yes, "functional language").

start to know new language, "back to the basics". 
I have read some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606469/evaluation-in-scheme) and answers but it is not exactly what I want to know or what I am confusing (for now... maybe later, can be better..)

**Question 1.** 
What exactly **"evaluation" means in Scheme ?** and Scheme also using "evaluation of environment" = putting in stack?? assign memory???. how differ from execution?

**Question 2.**
**Is** **environment** similar definition to "agreement , **parameters**" in a function?

**Question 3.** **"initial value" in Scheme**, and "initial value" other procedural programming (c/c++) are same meaning? usually initial value in procedural language is the value you have to assign before the program run... usually 0, null,... the starting address of memory... etc... but my impression in Scheme's "initial value" is a bit different. Scheme "initial value" = the function itself (at least in recursion)... Can anyone explain this clear with very plain expression (no "buzz Scheme" words) ???

**Question 4.** then it seems you can explain the difference between let, letrec, let* with evaluation. (not sure..yet). 
something like this (could be completely wrong...),

4-1) ["When a normal "let" **is evaluated**, the initial value expressions are evaluated before binding is done."] means? = (with my words) when let **is executed**?? and I don't understand.. this "the initial value expressions are evaluated before binding is done."
How it can evaluate before binding is done...?? what exactly mean "binding is done"???

4-2) ["let*": when an order is important,  **evaluates the environment** (parameter?) step by step along with the order program lines(???) ] by this explanation, to me, evaluates = executes.... => (my interpretation, "let*"  assign memory and executes for each parameters step by step along with the order of program line???

4-3) "letrec" : ["letrec lets us **create an environment before evaluating the initial value**(??) expressions, so that the initial value **computations execute inside the new environment**(*my interpretation* this sounds for tail recursion)]." => creates an environment before evaluating the initial value, how?

**Question 5.**
There is no initialization, declaration... in Scheme?

Sorry for a long question and it maybe too basic to others. but it will help me clear things out in Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1 Evaluation

Evaluation is the process of running a bit of code to it's result. eg. `(+ 1 2) ;==> 3`. In this particular example `+` is  free variable that needs to be in the environment. It might evaluate to the global prcedure `+` or it might be that it's a lexical variable from code run before this.

## 2 Environment

Environment is the variables accessable at a certain point. eg.

```
(define x 10)
(define f1 (lambda (y) (+ x y))
(define f2 (let ((x 5))
              (lamdba (y) (+ x y))))
```

The lambda forms that cerate `f1` and `f2` are equal in the sense they do the exact same thing. The difference in the environment.

```
(f1 3) ; ==> 13
(f2 3) ; ==> 8
```

The scope of `f2`'s `x` is no more but it's referenced in the `procedure` and accessible when running it but not from any other place. An evaluated `lambda` form (ie. a procedure) is also known as a closure since the variables accessable at the point of evaluation is accessible when applying the result of that lambda form (the procedure).

## 3 Initial value

When starting up a Scheme program you have an initial global environment. variables like `+` and `cons` are defined. I'm not sure this is what you were after. Perhaps you should give an example of what you were thinking?

## 4 `let`, `let*`, `letrec`, and `lambda`

You have these in all examples:

```
(define x 10)
(define f (lambda (x) x)
```

Everyone of them turns into anonymous `lambda` function calls. I'll just do one level, but since you can transform `let*` into `let` and `let` into `lambda` you can transform everyone of these to lots of `lambda` forms. Here's how:

`(let ((a 1) (b 2) ...) body ...)` is the same as  `((lambda (a b ..) body ...) 1 2 ...)` thus this is true:

```
(let ((x 5) (y (+ x 1)) (f (lambda (x) (if (< 5 x) (f (- x 1)) x))))
  (list x y (f 10))) ; ==> (5 11 9)
```

`(let ((a 1) (b 2)) body ...)` is the same as `(let ((a 1)) (let ((b 2)) body ...)` thus this is true:

```
(let* ((x 5) (y (+ x 1)) (f (lambda (x) (if (< 5 x) (f (- x 1)) x))))
  (list x y (f 10))) ; ==> (5 6 9)
```

`(letrec ((a 1) (b 2)) body ...)` is the same as `(let ((a 'undef) (b 'undef)) (let ((tmpa 1) (tmpb 2)) (set! a tmpa) (set! b tmpb)) body ...)` thus this is true:

```
(letrec ((x 5) (y (list x 1)) (f (lambda (x) (if (< 5 x) (f (- x 1)) x))))
  (list x y (f 10))) ; ==> (5 (undef 1) 5)
```

Note i changed `+` to `list` since `(+ 'undef 1)` won't work. Your Scheme implementation might use any value in place of `undef`. When to use what? Use ``letrec`and named`let`for procedures that you need to recurse, use`let*`for variables where you rely on a previous calculation (it keeps you from writing nested`let`forms and use`let` as much as you can.

So imagine you have a procedure that is not recursive, a variable and a variable you derive you can use `let*`:

```
(let* ((sq (lambda (x) (* x x))) ; given this is a top level it will have global environment
       (x (sq 5))
       (y (sq 10))
       (res (+ x y)) ; here I'm using both x and y
  (do-something res))
```

## 5 declarations

There is. If I want to make global variables I do it like this:

```
(define test 55)
(define fun (lambda (x) (+ test x))
```

Comment: 1. then can I say evaluation is equivalent to execution? well, execution is for the output, then "the process of running" can be also execution?
2. so environment => parameters and the logic for the parameters 
3. I think my problem is connected with tail recursion for this issue. In tail recursion, in the end, you have to call yourself and sometimes (I could be wrong) I saw it is called also "initial value" ...but this is really because of the confusion about tail recursion.. so I can't explain exactly...
4. I need to look at step by step -- I would like to come back for it. 
5.. Ahh..

Comment: 5. then can we call the declaration (here 55) as "initial value" like other programming languages?

Comment: @user1915570 1. You have optimizations but if you look past that evaluation is still the process of running code. 2. Scheme environment is special and different than static languages. It cannot be contained in a stack since it branches like a tree. To truly understand it you should implement Scheme `eval` or [watch the wizards at work](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/7a-metacircular-evaluator-part-1). 5. Yes, but it's common to treat them almost like constants.

Comment: How to print the content of the initial envirement?

Comment: Scheme has lexical scoping of bound variables so if there is a name collision the inner variable value will be used?

Comment: @X10D There is no way to list the environment in a compatible way. If you know the bindings you are after you can just print them. As with all lexical scope the closest binding is the winner. You are not allowed to have the same name in the same `let` form, but it is underspecifiied what will happen. Eg. `(let* ((a 10) (a 20)) (list a))` might do anything even make the result `(banana)`.